# Not CPA secure for CBC mode if some code are changed that is if we replaced a function $\pi(k,x)=k\oplus x$

Tags: cryptography

Consider the CBC mode where the block cipher is replaced by a function $\pi$ where $\pi(k,x)=k\oplus x$. Show that the mode is not CPA secure.

I am not got how to proceed to solve this question. Please someone helps me out to know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If we choose some string of our choice, lets say we chose $s:=0^n$. Then, $\pi(k,s)$ would be the cyphertext, but $$\pi(k,s)=k\oplus s=k\oplus 0^n=k$$

Which means that we can very easily extract the (first) key. In fact, this works for any string $s$ we want:

Define $k':=s\oplus \pi(k,s)$. Notice that we know how to compute $k'$ since we chose $s$ and got $\pi(k,s)$ (we still don't know $k$). But, we can calculate the following: $$k'=s\oplus \pi(k,s)=s\oplus (k\oplus s) = s\oplus (s\oplus k) = (s\oplus s)\oplus k = 0^n\oplus k = k$$

Hence, $k'=k$ and thus we actually calculated what the key is.